# Can multiple groups of HTML radio buttons be made to return a PHP array after a submit?

Tags: php, html, arrays, post, radio-button

I have a simple dynamically-created HTML page to list database records that may or may not be deleted or restored, basically a recycle bin. This list can have any number of records. I had aimed to show these records, each with an individual HTML radio button group at the start of each row, with the choices of Restore, Keep and Delete.

```html
<form action="this page.php" method="post">

Decide what to do with each record (R=Restore, K=Keep in Bin, D=Delete):<br><br>

<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit this form"><br>
<input type="reset" value="Choose to keep in bin"><br><br>


R &nbsp; &nbsp; K &nbsp; &nbsp; D<br>
<input type="radio" name="100" value="Restore">
<input type="radio" name="100" value="Keep" checked>
<input type="radio" name="100" value="Delete">
A record from the database, that has an internal id number of 100.<br>

<input type="radio" name="101" value="Restore">
<input type="radio" name="101" value="Keep" checked>
<input type="radio" name="101" value="Delete">
Another record from the database, that has an internal id number of 101.<br>

<input type="radio" name="999" value="Restore">
<input type="radio" name="999" value="Keep" checked>
<input type="radio" name="999" value="Delete">
Yet another record from the database, that has an internal id number of 999.<br>

</form>
```

I do not know which records or how many will be in the list, so I can't give the radio button groups set names. I had wanted to handle the resultant Restore and Delete SQL queries on the database via an array, but I can't figure out how to create such an array.
In the example I've shown, I'd need to know that name="100", name="101 ... name="999" are being returned in the $_POST. I had initially tried to use checkboxes, one group for each of the Restore, Keep and Delete columns, each providing an array with the internal ids listed, but, user-wise, it wasn't as intuitive as radio buttons as more than one action could be requested.
Is there an HTML/PHP technique I'm missing (I don't know Javascript)? (Aside: I've tried extracting all the $_POST information from var_dump, but I'm getting nowhere.)

Comment: As its the `name="100"` attribute that is converted to a PHP variable, use a valid name, PHP wont create variables that start with a numeric

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I suppose my example was made a bit too simple. However, even if I use ID100, ID101 ... ID999, I'd still need to know the variable names to address them. I'm looking to get something like ID[ID100=>"Keep", ID101=>"Delete" ...], etc.

Comment: This wont work per default. You could a javascript listener to prevent the submit, build the array by yourself and sending it from there - or you could group it in backend by checking $_POST varname ....

Comment: Make each an array `name="ID100[]"`

Comment: Just like with any other inputs, if you use square bracket array annotation, you'll receive an array on the other end. I think the closest to what you want is `name="id[100]"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to submit an array of values, all you need to do is use the square bracket annotation inside the name attribute: `name="someName[]"` and PHP will detect it as an array when submitted.

Now if you organize your elements in this fashion:

```html
<form method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="id[100]" value="Restore">
    <input type="radio" name="id[100]" value="Keep">
    <input type="radio" name="id[100]" value="Delete">

    <input type="radio" name="id[101]" value="Restore">
    <input type="radio" name="id[101]" value="Keep">
    <input type="radio" name="id[101]" value="Delete">

    <input type="radio" name="id[999]" value="Restore">
    <input type="radio" name="id[999]" value="Keep">
    <input type="radio" name="id[999]" value="Delete">

    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send">
</form>
```

and submit the form, the `$_POST` variable will capture the values like this:

```php
array(
    'id' => array(
        100 => 'Restore',
        101 => 'Keep',
        999 => 'Delete',
    ),
    'send' => 'Send',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$allIdFields = array_filter($_POST, function($name) { return substr($name,0,2) === 'ID'); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
var_dump($allIdFields);
?>
```

In case only these fields starts with ID, just filter your array and check for the beginning string. https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter